# How can I add an event handler to a text node in DOM tree without affecting its style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to add event handlers to words in text nodes in DOM tree **without modifying how they look**.
Currently I just split the words in a text node and wrap them in separate `<span>` tags.

It basically turn:

```html
    <div className='parent-of-text'>
      Have a good day
    </div>
```

into:

```html
    <div className='parent-of-text'>
      <span onClick={doSomething}>
        Have
      </span> 
      <span onClick={doSomething}>
        a
      </span> 
      <span onClick={doSomething}>
        good
      </span> 
      <span onClick={doSomething}>
        day
      </span>
    </div>
```

However, in some cases, there may be some CSS rules that dictate the style of `<span>` that are direct descendants of `parent-of-text` class:

Say:

```css
.parent-of-text > span {
  color: red;
}
```

In cases like this, what can I do to avoid the effects of such CSS rules?

Comment: event handlers doesn't affect css style, what is your point ?

Comment: Give your new spans a class and either modify the existing rule(s) with a `:not` selector or write more specific rules for your `span.myClass`

Answer (score 0):

When you generate your span with JS (you didn't show us relevant code) apply inline style on those spans, this will overwrite presented CSS style for that element.

Also this has nothing to do with DOM, JS and  event handlers, this is only CSS applying styles issue.

```css
.parent-of-text>span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent-of-text'>
  Have a good day
</div>


<div class='parent-of-text'>
  <span onClick={doSomething} style="color: black">
        Have
      </span>
  <span onClick={doSomething}>
        a
      </span>
  <span onClick={doSomething} style="color: black">
        good
      </span>
  <span onClick={doSomething}>
        day
      </span>
</div>
```